# Android Questionaire

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I've an activity with 8 questions, every question has one 1 radiogroup with 2 radio buttons (Yes / No). On .xml I set checked the "No" radiobutton on all questions.

```
android:checked="true"
```

Do I need to check if one of the Radio Buttons is selected?
Can the user unselect both radiobuttons?

Sorry this noob question, but I cannot have unfilled answers.

Comment: Is there any doubt remaining?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to flag as correct your answer. I've another question. All my "Yes" radio button call the same activity, how can I implement the OnCheckedChangeListener to all "yes" Radio's have the same behavior? Do I have to a switch/case for all of them ?

Comment: You can set the OnCheckedChangeListener for the radio group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check radio button is selected or not.
User cannot unselect both radiobutton as per default behaviour of radio group

Answer (score 0):

There is a `clearCheck` method in RadioGroup. I don't think it is accessible through the UI as of today, but it may become so.

I would recommand handling the case with

```
if (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
    // Alert, or simply don't go to next question
}
```

or with a `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`. in `onCheckedChanged`, if checkedId is -1, disable the posibility to validate the answer, for example.